# UILabel, TextField with overstrike character

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel, strikethrough

I want to create a UILabel or UITextField with an overstruck character. (not a strikethru dash)For example:

[image]

is this possible in Swift 4/5 (Not SwiftUI). The hope is that this will roll into a text to show a correction and that the user adapting size will size as appropriate.

Note, I referenced several other questions and haven't found one that addresses character over character; only strikethru.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSAttributedString`, and set the below attribute:

```
let att = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "kfill")
att.addAttribute(.kern, value: -7, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 1))
label.attributedText = att
```

You can change the `range` and `value` if you wish to achieve different results.